# XML Injection C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0, fortify

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(template);
XmlElement list = doc.CreateElement(conn.XmlListTagName);
foreach (EaiItem updateItem in itemList)
{
    XmlElement item = doc.CreateElement( conn.XmlItemTagName );
    foreach(String itemAttrib in updateItem.ItemAttributes.Keys)
    {
        item.SetAttribute(itemAttrib, updateItem.ItemAttributes[itemAttrib]);
    }
    item.InnerXml = updateItem.ItemFieldXml;
    list.AppendChild(item);
}
doc.LastChild.AppendChild(list);
```

Fortify tool displaying the xml injection in the below code

```
 item.InnerXml = updateItem.ItemFieldXml;
```

How to prevent the xml injection issue ?

Comment: What is the problem? I assume `ItemFieldXml` contains XML that you want to insert into your document as a child XML fragment of your `item` element? or do you want it stored as `CDATA`?

Answer (score 1):

If your `ItemFieldXml` should be stored as `CDATA` in your XML instead of as *actual* XML, then use `XmlDocument.CreateCDataSection`:

So instead of this:

```
item.InnerXml = updateItem.ItemFieldXml;
list.AppendChild( item );
```

Do this:

```
XmlCDataSection cdata = doc.CreateCDataSection( updatedItem.ItemFieldXml );
item.AppendChild( cdata );
list.AppendChild( item );
```

That will render as this:

```
<item>
<![CDATA[
<foo>embedded XML that is escaped!</foo>
]]>
</item>
```

The `<foo>` text will *not* be interpreted as actual XML by conforming XML parsers.

An alternative is to create a Text node where the angle-brackets will be converted to the XML entities `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&amp;`. Using `CDATA` will be more efficient if you have many angle-brackets because it will require less space.

```
item.InnerText = updatedItem.ItemFieldXml;
list.AppendChild( item );
```

This will render as:

```
<item>
&lt;foo&gt;embedded XML that is escaped!&lt;/foo&gt;
</item>
```